# Datetime return dates between weekdays

Tags: python, datetime

If today is represented as follows:

```
todayStr = datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
todayStr

'09012021'
```

How do I get a list of values for:

Dates `>=` last Monday but `<` Thursday

For example today it would be:

```
['04012021','05012021','06012021']
```

Dates `>=` last Thursday but `<` Monday

Today it would be:

```
['07012021','08012021','09012021']
```

Comment: @S3DEV If OP is not already using pandas, using it only to calculate a date range is a rediculous overhead.

Comment: You should fix the definition (or the example) for the second list: dates there are >= last Thursday but < Sunday (not Monday)

Comment: @DeepSpace - Absolutely agree!  Hadn’t tweaked OP wasn’t already using pandas (although plainly obvious) ... oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
prev_monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
dates1 = [(prev_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%d%m%Y") for d in range(3)]
dates2 = [(prev_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%d%m%Y") for d in range(3, 6)]

print(dates1)
print(dates2)
```

produces:

```sh
['04012021', '05012021', '06012021']
['07012021', '08012021', '09012021']
```